# Facebook Popup in Query.ajax(){ success: }

Tags: jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

Facebook login popup not executed, why? JS not open any popup

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api/ajax/facebook/publish.stream.php",
    success: function(result)
    {  

       FB.login(function(res) {});


    }
});
```

I FOUND OUT THAT MY BROWSER(CHROME) BLOCK POPUP OF FACEBOOK LOGIN BECAUSE IT'S OPENED BY A NOT-CLICK USER EVENT, BUT BY AN AJAX SUCCESS REQUEST!!

Comment: I think the problem starts with Facebook, and ends with this question.

Comment: More detail, where are you calling the FB JS code, all that jazz

Comment: Why it should? how about editing your question and describe *what you want to do* **and** *what this code does*!

Comment: alert('here it's ok!'); => alert("here it's ok!");

Comment: Once again, don't just edit the code...explain what are you trying to do? what is the purpose of the ajax call and why using the `FB.login` this why?

Comment: I FOUND OUT THAT MY BROWSER(CHROME) BLOCK POPUP OF FACEBOOK LOGIN BECAUSE IT'S OPENED BY A NOT-CLICK USER EVENT, BUT BY AN AJAX SUCCESS REQUEST!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api/ajax/facebook/publish.stream.php",
    success: function(result)
    {  
       var result = $.parseJSON(result);

       if(result.login)
       {
           alert("here it's ok!");
           FB.login(function(res) {

           });

       }
       else
       {
           alert(result.string);
       }            
    }
});
```